# python: not write last bytes tcp?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

Hello I wrote a simple programs that transfer files but I have a problem: the programs do not send me a complete file and stop in while condition.

Server source:

```
#simple transfer files server
import socket, sys

SRV_ADDR = ""
SRV_PORT = 9900

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((SRV_ADDR, SRV_PORT))
s.listen(1)
connection, address = s.accept()

while 1:
    pippo = connection.recv(1024)   

    if(pippo.decode('utf-8') == '3'):
       riceivename=connection.recv(1024)
       lettore=riceivename.decode('utf-8')
       file = open(lettore, 'rb') 

       while 1:
           data = file.read(1024)
           if not data: break
           connection.sendall(data)
       file.close()
       print("ok end cicle")   
           
           
    elif(data.decode('utf-8') == '0'):
          connection.close()
          connection, address = s.accept()
```

Client:

```
import sys
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9900))

def print_menu():
    print("""\n\n0) Close the connection
3) Receive file""")

print("Connection established")
print_menu()

while 1:
    message = input("\n-Select an option: ")

    if (message=="3"):
        sock.sendall(message.encode())
        localname=input("name with which you want to save the file:")
        file = open(localname, 'wb') 
        path=input("insert remote path of file to be downloaded:")
        sock.sendall(path.encode())

        while 1:
           data=sock.recv(1024)
           if not data:break
           file.write(data)
        file.close()

    elif(message=="0"):
         sock.sendall(message.encode())
         sock.close()
         break

    print_menu()
```

I think that the client does not write the last byte.
I do not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your client is blocked at `data=sock.recv(1024)`. Because the server has not closed the connection, more data could still be sent by the server, so the client waits. You can check this by sending a file and, when the client is blocked at `recv()`, kill the server process. The client's `recv()` will then return `''` and will then close the file. The source and destination files should compare equal.

The proper solution is to close the socket in the server after all data has been sent to the client. You also need to move the `accept()` inside the loop so that further requests can be processed from a new client connection. Here is a revised server:

```
#simple transfer files server
import socket, sys

SRV_ADDR = ""
SRV_PORT = 9900

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((SRV_ADDR, SRV_PORT))
s.listen(1)

while 1:
    connection, address = s.accept()
    pippo = connection.recv(1024)

    if(pippo.decode('utf-8') == '3'):
       riceivename=connection.recv(1024)
       lettore=riceivename.decode('utf-8')
       file = open(lettore, 'rb')

       while 1:
           data = file.read(1024)
           if not data: break
           connection.sendall(data)
       connection.close()
       file.close()
       print("ok end cicle")

    elif(data.decode('utf-8') == '0'):
          connection.close()
```

And here's a revised client:

```
import sys
import socket

def print_menu():
    print("""\n\n0) Close the connection
3) Receive file""")

while 1:
    print_menu()
    message = input("\n-Select an option: ")

    if (message=="3"):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9900))
        print("Connection established")
        sock.sendall(message.encode())
        localname=input("name with which you want to save the file:")
        file = open(localname, 'wb')
        path=input("insert remote path of file to be downloaded:")
        sock.sendall(path.encode())

        while 1:
           data=sock.recv(1024)
           if not data:break
           file.write(data)
        file.close()
        sock.close()

    elif(message=="0"):
         sock.sendall(message.encode())
         sock.close()
         break
```

The client establishes a new connection for each file transfer. The "0" option is no longer useful, but I have left it in the code.

If you do not want to have new connections made each time, then you will need to have some way of indicating to the client that the file transfer has been completed. This will be hard to do while the connection is used for data transfer as well as command. Closing the socket is the easiest way to solve this problem.